# Utilize WCF Service in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I hosted some WCF Services on my client machine and this machine is connected to internet through any DSL. So, there is no live IP or any other static IP associated with it. Now, I want to utilize these WCF Services on my webpages through Asp.Net.

I need to ask, is this possible to access WCF services hosted on a machine which is connected through simple internet?

Few other things to keep in mind that, client (WCF services hosted) and server (Asp.Net pages hosted) in totally different domain. But, I know client machine IP or MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use services like [www.dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com) to setup something like that.